# Firebase Firestore not connecting with php

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and am struggling to connect it to a VM instance running PHP. I am able to make a connection to the cloud firestore database in PHP but only in the command line of the VM instance (e.g typing php index.php) but get a HTTP error 500 when I go to the website through a browser.

bellow is the PHP code that I have. I am just very confused why it works in the instane command line but not through the browser.

```
<?php

require (__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Kreait\Firebase\Firestore;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$db = new FirestoreClient([
        'projectId' => 'myprojectID',
    ]);

//$docRef = $db->collection('contact')->document('id1')->snapshot()->data();
//echo(print_r($docRef));
$usersRef = $db->collection('LoginData');
$snapshot = $usersRef->documents();

//add info

foreach ($snapshot as $user) {
    printf('User: %s' . PHP_EOL, $user->id());
    //echo($user->id());
}


?>
```

Comment: Just FYI, the code you're using is not making use of the Firebase SDK. In its current form, it will look for the authentication credentials (needed to connect with the Google/Firebase APIs) in the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I assume that this variable is set in your command line environment, but not in your Webserver environment.

Comment: How would i  go about setting up the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the webser environment? @jeromegamez. Bit of a noob with this

Comment: All good now, added putenv and forgot to add the grpc extension to the apache2 php.ini file. thanks for your help :)